# Azure App Service SQL Database Backup Fails

Tags: sql, azure, backup

I am having issues creating a backup of SQL db with my Azure App Service. In the Azure Portal, when I go to backup I am seeing this error:

> Create Database copy of [database] threw an exception. Could not
> create Database copy. Make sure to use the admin user in the database
> connection string.

I get this error means the user does not have the correct permissions, but I am not able to grant the correct permissions. I have tried the following so far:

- Created an Azure Active Directory user and set it as admin for the sql server in the portal
- Added role "dbmanager" and "loginmanager" to the user
- Created the user in master and tried adding permissions there but it gives the error `it does not exist or you do not have permission`

I am not sure what else to do. Seems like when I create a new SQL instance in Azure it doesn't give the admin user all permissions.

Comment: Hi @Scott, please correct me if I understand you wrong in the answer.  : )

Comment: Hi @Scott, you must grant the permissions in different user dbs. Kindly let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we can not add permissions to the user in **master** db, when we try to do this, it will give us the error `it does not exist or you do not have permission`. **master** db is usually used to create login. Please switch to user db.

1. We can use the following T-sql to create an AAD user. Then AAD user can login to the `UserDB`, but by default the AAD user doesn't have any permissions to control the `UserDB`.

```sql
use <UserDB>;
CREATE USER [bob@example.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
```

2. Then we can execute T-sql to add permissions to the AAD user of the `UserDB`. So that the AAD user can perform database DDL operations.

```sql
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', [bob@example.com]
```

Comment: Hi @Scott, If my answer is helpful for you, please accept(mark) it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Very thanks!